# how to sort(arrange) tables of entity framework database model in Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework

I want to sort tables of entity framework database model in visual studio 2008. But I can't find how to accomplish that. But it's possible to "arrange tables" in sql server diagrams for making table relationships more clear.

Does visual studio have the functionality(menu or shortcut etc) for that?

**Edit:**

Finally I've managed to finish this manually. And I've not found answers on the internet for solving it automatically in visual studio.

Tips for relationships between tables: You just put your cursor over the boundary of the link and a table when you want move the "relation" between two tables. You can move the relation as it shows a black diamond icon(not white diamond icon).

Comment: a year and a version later and there is still no easy way to do this :(

Answer (score 53):

In Visual Studio 2012 right click on the empty space of your diagram in the designer, select Diagram->Layout Diagram.